# Is it possible to have more joint tenants in equity than the number of joint tenants in law?

Tags: england-and-wales, property, equity

Dealing specifically with England and Wales:

Is it possible for there to be more joint tenants in equity for a specific property than the number of joint tenants in law?

For example, if A, B, C contribute to the purchase of a property, is it possible for only two of these parties to be legal joint tenants, whilst all three parties are beneficial joint tenants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is fairly common for there to be one owner at law, but another person who has a beneficial interest - such as a long-term cohabiting partner. This may arise because the parties set it up that way, or perhaps more often when courts find that there is a "constructive trust" or a "resulting trust". See for example the concurring opinion of Lord Hope of Craighead in [Stack v Dowden [2007] UKHL 17](http://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKHL/2007/17.html),

> Parties are, of course, free to enter into whatever bargain they wish and, so long as it is clearly expressed and can be proved, the court will give effect to it. But for the rest the state of the legal title will determine the right starting point. The onus is then on the party who contends that the beneficial interests are divided between them otherwise than as the title shows to demonstrate this on the facts.

The resulting court process may find that the beneficial interest exists, or not, and what fraction of the property it represents. It's common to find situations where one party put up most or all of the whole purchase price of a house, which was then registered in both names, and they then disagree about whether it should be split 50-50 or otherwise - that's an example of the beneficial ownership differing in proportion from the (equal) legal ownership. (See [Jones v Kernott [2011] UKSC 53](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2011/53.html) at paragraph 51 for an explanation of this particular pattern.)

The same sort of case arises when a cohabiting partner does not own the house, but still contributes to the mortgage and other bills - then, depending on the facts at hand, there may be a "constructive trust", and the partner is entitled to a share of the sale price of the house even though they are not its legal owner. A "resulting trust" might arise when someone contributed money for the purchase of the property, even though they didn't end up as a registered owner, but the parties acted in other respects as if they were joint owners.

Comment: How does this work with the 4 unities, one of which is unity of title?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is Yes.

Comment: It seems that this answer is lacking a lot in quality and can basically be summed up as the word Yes.

Comment: The question only asks if such an ownership can exist in equity and the answer is yes. I does not ask for examples of how it could arise.

Comment: I understand what it is asking but that doesn't make what is basically a single word answer good.

Comment: @JoeW Why not? Can you give a rationale for your assertion?

Comment: Because it provides no details to explain the answer or evidence to support it. The other answer on this question is a good example of providing needed details.

Comment: The other answer also does not explain why it is possible. The question is a bit like asking if it is possible to get car which runs on petrol. The answer is yes. You can't really say *why* that is possible unless the questioner gives some hint as to why they might think it might not be possible. Giving details of a number of makes of petrol cars is interesting but does not actually improve the answer IMO.

Comment: That answer at least made an attempt at explaining the answer while this one doesn't and leaves it up to the viewer to actually figure out what it means. As for your silly example you don't have to give examples of cars that run on petrol but could explain how most cars are designed to run on it.

Comment: Sorry for trying to provide feedback on an answer to help improve the quality of it.

Comment: In my experience when someone asks a very simple question the answer to which will be obvious to anyone who knows anything about the subject (in this case land law in England and Wales) it is usually because they have been reading about the subject using texts which assume the very basic knowledge and so do not spell the very simple things out. The most helpful way of answering in these circumstances is to take the ultra simple question at face value and answer it directly.

Comment: Attacking the question because your answer was pointed out as being low quality? What the question is like doesn't change the fact that what is essentially a single word answer is  low quality.

Comment: Not an attack. Just an explanation of my rationale. The OP now has two answers and can choose which they find most helpful.

Comment: Sure seemed like one to me because the quality of the question should have no impact at all on the quality of the answer. You decided to answer the question.

Comment: It is not a *low quality* question, hust a simple one.

Comment: And a simple question doesn't deserve what is essentially a single word answer. It still deserves an explanation.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree on that one.